# How spring statemachine coveys error to caller in case of missing transitions?

Tags: java, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have one state-machine instance for each conversation(each trade inquiry).
trade inquiry moves through different states on receiving events and some stats might not be valid.

Example->States: a,b,c,d,e Transitions/events: E1,E2,E3,E4,E5 
state-machine is something like :
 a--E1-->b---E2-->c--E5--> e

I have statemachine listener registered with  builder as:
 StateMachine machine = builder.build();
machine.addStateListener(new StateMachineListener());

This StateMachineListener just throws the RuntimeException in-case event is not accepted but execption is not being passed to caller instead get printed in logs due to code at CompositeStateMachineListener.eventNotAccepted.

My query is : How statemachine can notify the caller in case event is not accepted?

Answer (score 0):

This would not work as `StateMachineListener` is just an interface. There is a `StateMachineListenerAdapter` which implements full stub methods which user can then override one-by-one.